# Qt: запрос к бд содержащий переменную

Tags: sql, qt

сам в бд не сильно шарю, поэтому ответ найти не получается. В коде ниже закомментирован name, это строка с именем столбца в бд. Собственно хочу чтобы обращение к бд содержало эту строку, однако как ее обозначить как переменную, а не как имя?

```
       QSqlDatabase db;
       db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
       db.setDatabaseName("C:\\Temperaturies.db3");
       db.open();
       if(!db.open())
           QMessageBox::critical(this, "Ошибка", "база не открывается");

       QSqlQuery query;
       query.exec("SELECT //name FROM Temperaturies");
'''
```

Comment: `query.bindValue(...);` Читайте документацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это имелось ввиду?

```
query.prepare("SELECT ? FROM Temperaturies");
query.bindValue(0, "name");
query.exec();
```

Или

```
query.prepare("SELECT :name FROM Temperaturies");
query.bindValue(":name", "name");
query.exec();
```